# Namespaces in TCL

Tags: namespaces, tcl

I was reading about namespaces in TCL from the book **Practical Programming in TCL**
The chapter opens up with the paragraph shown in the attached image : [image]

I have a doubt related to the second paragraph where author stated that *"one global namespace for procedures"*
My doubt is : We have a global scope (where we can define procedures and variables) , local scope within procedures , and some namespaces (inside the global namespace , `::Namespc1`) if we further create any namespaces. Then what is the author referring to by the same statement which I mentioned above ?

Please help me understand this.

Thanks

Comment: That was the situation in old versions before namespaces.

Comment: And what does the line highlighted in green mean ?

Comment: That describes the current state.

Answer (score 2):

Originally, before Tcl 8.0, commands were all placed in the global scope, and variables were either in the global scope or local to a procedure. With Tcl 8.0, namespaces were introduced (they were adaptations of a feature that had previously been an extension) and the global scope became the global namespace. The only truly special features of the global namespace by comparison with all its children are that it is where commands are looked up by default when not found in the current namespace, and it is where the `global` command looks up variables.

These days, both scopes and namespaces are things that can be on the stack. The difference between them is that scopes are unnamed temporary things associated with a running procedure (or lambda or method; these use the same machinery under the hood) and namespaces are named permanent things that last until deleted. Also, scopes can *only* hold variables and are always associated with a particular namespace; for procedures, that's the namespace that the procedure's been placed within, for lambdas, that's the namespace that is declared in the descriptor (or the global namespace if none is given), and for methods, that's the namespace of the current instance object.

There are other things going on as well, but you can usually ignore them.

Comment: Strictly, I think it is a sort of delegate that's actually pushed when a namespace is the current stack frame, but unless you're deep in the implementation of how namespaces and the stack work, you can ignore that. I certainly almost always ignore it!

Answer (score 0):

You might also acquire "The Tcl Programming Language: A Comprehensive Guide":

https://www.magicsplat.com/ttpl/index.html

It is really comprehensive and modern.

Comment: Also a lot of good material on author's blog